# How can I display text from my Firestore database unto my flutter app?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, storage

[image: My fire store database]What i am trying to do is get data from the "username" field within a user id from my "users" collection in fire store.
So far i am able to write to fire store but not retrieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very general question but I will step you through all of the steps in order to get the username field from a specific user. First of all you need to make sure that in your pubspec.yaml file you have the dependencies for the cloud_firestore dart package. Next, you are going to need to build the following code,

```
class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {

  Future getUserData() async {
    var firestore = Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection("users").getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getUserData(),
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Text(snapshot.data[index].data['User Name']);
            }
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This code will get all of the documents in the users collection and then will print the value of the "User Name" field of all of the documents in that collection. Hope this helps!

Comment: I already saw similar code to do this in several articles. Thihs prints the username to the debug console. I want to display the User Name on the screen. Thanks though

Comment: If you would like to display the User Name on the screen you can just change the print line to Text(snapshot.data[index].data[‘User Name’])

Comment: Yeah, after some hours i realised that. Sorry, i'm a bit new to flutter. Thanks a lot.